# Android: Soft Keyboard Open & Hide Custom Dialog w/ multiple edit texts

Tags: android, dialog, keyboard, android-edittext

Ok - I've bonked my head quite a bit with this.  I have a custom dialog which has multiple edittexts.  I've set my layout so that it does not automatically focus on the first as both are initially filled with default values (thus the user may just press 'accept')

I want any edittext to clear itself when touched and open a keyboard for numeric input. They may change one or both fields.  If they touch and do not input, the field should change back to a default value.

I have implemented this with setOnFocusChangedListeners in addition to the addTextChangedListeners.
My first problem occured with the realization that the keyboard was toggling itself open/closed when a user touched both edittexts.  I resolved this by using SHOW_FORCED,HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS as parameters to toggleSoftInput. Note that this was the only set of parameters which kept the keyboard open when a second field was touched.

Unfortunately, this has created a second problem which I do not understand - on exiting the dialog, I can no longer close the keyboard (ie, it remains visible on the following view).  Previously, when I did not make an effort to clear the input, keyboards closed out ok.  Using SHOW_IMPLICIT (ignoring the toggle issue) also has no problem with an open keyboard being closed on exit.

So.. how the * do I get this to work?

Below are some relevant sections of code:

```
            edQuantity.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"edQuantity focus changed");
                    if (hasFocus) {
                        Log.i(TAG,"edQuantity HAS FOCUS");
                        edQuantity.setHint("");
                        edQuantity.setText("");
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                    }

                    // was the other field left empty after a change attempt?
                    if (String.valueOf(edPrice.getText()).length()==0) edPrice.setText("0.01");  
                }
            });


            edPrice.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"edPrice focus changed");
                    if (hasFocus) {
                        Log.i(TAG,"edPrice HAS FOCUS");
                        edPrice.setHint("");
                        edPrice.setText("");
                       InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                       imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                    }

                    // was the other field left empty after a change attempt?
                    if (String.valueOf(edQuantity.getText()).length()==0) edQuantity.setText("1");
                }
            });


protected static void dismissCustomDialog(Dialog dialog, Context context) {

    if (dialog != null) {

        // hide the soft keyboard
        if (dialog.getCurrentFocus() != null) {

            Log.i(TAG,"trying to hide a keyboard");
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        }

        if(dialog.isShowing()) dialog.dismiss();

    }
}
```

Comment: It is cold and blustery outside.  I don't know why I did not think of this earlier.  I added a boolean keybdToggle initially set to false.  I then test it before opening a keyboard and if I do open a keybd I toggle it so no other keyboard open attempts are made.  Reverted back to using SHOW IMPLICIT and everything closes up nicely again.    Still no idea why they did not in the above.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment above, used a toggle to see if a keyboard was already opened.